# How to load files in a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following operations to be done on every single file loaded in MATLAB.

```
  A=file1
  A1=A(:,4)
  B=cumsum(tabletoarray(A1))
  secconv=A/1000
  time=datestr(C,'HH:MM:SS.FFFF')
```

I have 5000 .csv files in which the above operations has to be done. I need to load a file , do the operations , save the file under a new filename and repeat this for the next file. Is there a way to do this process efficiently in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the files present in the folder using *dir* and then running a loop for each file.

files = dir('*.csv') ;

```
N = length(files) ; % total number of files 
% loop for each file 
for i = 1:N
    thisfile = files(i).name ;
    % Read the file using csvread
    % do what you want
    % save the file using save/xlswrite
end
```

Comment: I did try this code before but the csvread doeasn't read my files. Getting an error at line 29 . My files have numeric, string and character data

Comment: @DaphFab `Getting an error at line 29` tells us nothing since we don't know the context at line 29. Please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.